# ByteStream problems

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how this code is working. It's using a byte stream:

```
in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
out = new FileOutputStream("x.txt");
int c;

while((c = in.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(c);   
}
```

What I don't understand is the `while` loop. Is the input stream working like an array where the index is being incremented, and that index is passed on to the output stream?

If some one could explain it would be greatly be appreciated.

Comment: in.read returns -1 at the end of the stream. The while loop assigns c to in.read() so long as there is more to read.

Comment: Stackoverflow is meant to answer real questions, not to explain your own code. Also, the title doesn't seem to match with the content of the question.

Comment: @rds - I think this is a fair enough beginner question about the mechanics of streams. Not like we're being asked to explain 400 lines of copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in.read(), I guess, acts like a for loop. it returns the next byte in the file, and increments *its* iterator by one. In a file with the text "Hello World", in.read() initially would yield 'H'. in.read() would then yield 'e', and so on, until the end of the file.

At the end of the file, in.read() cannot read any more bytes. The function is designed to exit gracefully from this state, by returning -1. Of course, bytes cannot have a value of -1; so, whenever you get a value of -1 from this method, you can be sure that it's at the end of the file.

while ((cin=in.read())!=-1){} does two things. First, it sets c equal to in.read(); then, it checks if it is equal to -1. If not, then it enters the loop body. Things in parentheses (even if they aren't necessarily arithmetic) are always evaluated before things outside of parentheses.

Comment: "in.read(), I guess, acts like a for loop" Thats what i was looking for. I wasnt understanding where the incrementation was taking place.

Answer (score 1):

[`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) reads a single byte from the stream. This byte is returned as an `int` value (0-255, since there is no unsigned byte in Java). If you receive `-1` from the stream, that means the end-of-stream `EOS` (which is the end of the file when using [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)).

---

Regarding the while loop:

```
while((c = in.read()) != -1)
```

`in.read()` is executed first, the value is assigned to `c`, then a boolean comparison `c != -1` is evaluated as while-loop argument.